# Getting the true labels for augmented data from Keras data generator when batch size is greater than 1 using flow_from_dataframe

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm using keras version 2.3.1 and tensorflow version on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I created my data generator as follows:

```
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(brightness_range=(0.5, 1.5), 
                                 preprocessing_function=densenet.preprocess_input)
    
    datagen = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df,
                                          x_col="Image Path",
                                          y_col=["class1", "class2", "class3"],
                                          class_mode="raw",
                                          shuffle=True,
                                          batch_size=32,
                                          seed=123,
                                          target_size=(256, 256))
```

Suppose the number of images in dataframe (df) is 100 images.  If I make prediction on this data generator as follows

```
probs = model.predict_generator(datagen, steps=datagen.n, verbose=1)
```

I will get the probs as arrays with dimension (3200, 3) because of the data augmentation.  However, when I try to link to the true labels using the following command.

```
y_true = datagen.labels
```

I got the array of y_true with dimension (100, 3) which is the labels of images before augmentation.  How can I like each augmented sample to its true label?  Since I configured my datagen to shuffle images, I'm not sure whether I can replicate each true label in y_true with the number of batch_size using this command or not.

```
y_true_augmented = np.repeat(y_true, repeats=32, axis=0)
```

May I have your suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the datagen is a generator and you have specified the random seed then can't you use something like:

```
y_true = []
for x,y in datagen:
 y_true.append(y)
```

for n steps and then pass the datagen to your model. Kidnly correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I did that but I got `too many values to unpack (expected 2)` from the line `for x, y in datagen`.

Comment: Finally, I found that modifying for loop to be `for _ , y , _ in datagen:` works nicely.  Thank you for your idea.